# How to make a advanced torso RIG with

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I'm learning rigging and most of the rig systems I found pretty easy to reproduce by watching videos and demos. I understand local\global\parent coordinates even creating complex bone based facial rigs, but...

I found realy dificult to create a more advanced rig for a torso.
something like that: https://youtu.be/im5XhbpGXjw
and even do not have ways to think how to describe this kind of rig.

how this hinge and pivot slide works?

Please, don't tell me to use the rigfy addon or blenrig, this is not my goal.
I'm trying to learn how does this stuff work, think will be usefull in future.

Comment: What is the question really? Certainly you are not expecting a full blown tutorial, nor that anyone does it for you.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, No, just some reference or a tip for how do this hinge and pivot slide works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huamne Rigging (same author as the Rigify and Sintel rigs afaik) has a section on how to build a spine rig. Its video 6 under the Mr Biped section.

It is on blender cloud if you have a sub (which I would encourage anyway, its good to support blender) https://cloud.blender.org/p/humane-rigging

Or if you really don't want to pay you could look on youtube, since its CC BY 3.0 licensed.

Answer (score 0):

That looks the [Sintel rig](https://cloud.blender.org/p/characters/5714e317c379cf04929a37f4) from Blender Foundation [Open Movie Durian Project](https://durian.blender.org/)  Sintel.

[image]

It is [open content freely available to anyone](https://cloud.blender.org/p/characters/), you can use it study it, modify it and redistribute it as you see fit, along with all assets and production files from the movie.

You can access it by subscribing to the [Blender Cloud](https://cloud.blender.org/) just like any of the content from all other [Blender Foundation Open Projects](https://www.blender.org/features/projects/) which will cost you a small symbolic monthly fee.

While doing so you will also be happy to know you are helping the Blender foundation monetarily, and funding Blender development that benefits everyone.